# Unity3d Transform.LookAt also changes position

Tags: unity-game-engine

Title says it all.

I provided an NPC with the following script, which should make him look and bark at the player.
When the player comes into the NPC's reach, however, the NPC starts walking towards the player instead of just facing him.

Any thoughts?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Barking : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioSource barkingAudio;

    private GameObject player;
    private bool barking;

    void Start () {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        barking = false;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (barking)
            lookAtPlayer();
    }

    private void lookAtPlayer()
    {
        transform.LookAt(player.transform.position, Vector3.up);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == player)
        {
            barking = true;
            barkingAudio.mute = false;
            barkingAudio.Play();
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == player) {
            barking = false;
            barkingAudio.mute = true;
            barkingAudio.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you comment out the transform.LookAt line? the only reason i could come up with why this would be moving your object is if the origin of your object isnt where you think it is and even then it wouldnt just move straight. my actual guess is that another script is responsible

Comment: When I comment out the transform.LookAt line, the NPC doesn't move anymore nor does it rotate to the player. This led me to believe the method was bugged.

Also, I don't refer to the NPC in any other source file.

Comment: - Update: removing the rigidbody component on the NPC solved my issue. Not sure how or why this happens though. Going to search some more on Google!

Comment: that does sound weird! but yeah if you have a rigidbody, you shouldnt change the transform in any way, but instead use the rigidbody functions. It also should probably be FixedUpdate then instead of Update

Answer (score 2):

Since I was using a Rigidbody and rotating the transform manually, there was some unexpected behaviour.

I found some code online which I could replace the Transform.LookAt method with:

```
    var qTo = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.transform.position - transform.position);
    qTo = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, qTo, 10 * Time.deltaTime);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MoveRotation(qTo);
```

This fixed my problem!

Comment: Worked for me well, thank you! Still not sure why transform.lookAt() makes my object fly.

Comment: This fixed my problem too, I'm sure its a bug in Unity as surely changing a transforms rotation shouldn't also move the object or in my case freeze the objects location when it was rotating. I had an object moving in a circle through space always .lookat the players ship. but when the ship moves the object stops moving and only rotates. As soon as my ship stops moving the object jumps to where it should have been all along.